# Create array of dictionary with different keys?

Tags: objective-c

I have following array,I have one array with multiple dictionaries,I need to get that dictionaries for same prod_type and create another array with unique key

```
nsarray
  {
    {
      prod_type=abc;
      fund=100;
     };
        {
      prod_type=abc;
      fund=100;
     };
   {
      prod_type=abc;
      fund=100;
     };
   {
      prod_type=pqr;
      fund=100;
     };
   {
      prod_type=pqr;
      fund=100;
     };
   {
      prod_type=xyz;
      fund=100;
     };
   {
      prod_type=xyz;
      fund=100;
     };
```

I need following array format from above array

```
 nsarray=
  {
     abc=
     {
     {
      prod_type=abc;
      fund=100;
     };
        {
      prod_type=abc;
      fund=100;
     };
   {
      prod_type=abc;
      fund=100;
     };
      }

   pqr=
      {
       {
      prod_type=pqr;
      fund=100;
     };
   {
      prod_type=pqr;
      fund=100;
     };
    }
 xyz=
     {
       {
      prod_type=xyz;
      fund=100;
     };
   {
      prod_type=xyz;
      fund=100;
     };

      }

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) to get desirable result.

```
NSString *selectedCategory=@"abc";

//filter array by category using predicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"prod_type == %@", selectedCategory];

NSArray *filteredArray = [yourAry filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSDictionary *abcDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:filteredArray forKey:@"abc"];

[yourNewAry addObject:abcDic];
```

You can repeat it for other

Here a nice explanation of it [predicates](http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2012/10/predicates.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use this code if you want a fully automated solution (without having to re-specify each `prod_type`):

```
NSMutableArray *keys = [originalArray mutableArrayValueForKey:@"prod_type"];
NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:keys];
NSArray *uniqueKeys = orderedSet.array;

NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSString *key in uniqueKeys){
    NSPredicate *keyPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"prod_type = %@",key];
    NSDictionary *keyDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[originalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:keyPredicate] forKey:key];
    [resultArray addObject:keyDictionary];
}

NSLog(@"%@",resultArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
    NSMutableDictionary *resultdict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *keysArray =[array mutableArrayValueForKey:@"prod_type"];//here you'l get all the prod_type values in an array
      for(int i=0;i<[keysArray count];i++){
          NSPredicate *resultPredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"prod_type CONTAINS %@",[keysArray objectAtIndex:i]];
          NSArray* searchResults=[array  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
          [resultdict setObject:searchResults forKey:[keysArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",resultdict);
```

EX:-

```
NSMutableArray *array =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:@[@"abc",@"100"] forKeys:@[@"name",@"value"]];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:@[@"pqr",@"100"] forKeys:@[@"name",@"value"]];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:@[@"pqr",@"100"] forKeys:@[@"name",@"value"]];

    [array addObject:dict];
    [array addObject:dict1];
    [array addObject:dict2];
```

### NSLog(@"%@",array);

```
(
        {
        name = abc;
        value = 100;
    },
        {
        name = pqr;
        value = 100;
    },
        {
        name = pqr;
        value = 100;
    }
)


NSMutableDictionary *resultdict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *keysArray =[array mutableArrayValueForKey:@"name"];
      for(int i=0;i<[keysArray count];i++){
          NSPredicate *resultPredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS %@",[keysArray objectAtIndex:i]];
          NSArray* searchResults=[array  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
          [resultdict setObject:searchResults forKey:[keysArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
```

### NSLog(@"%@",resultdict);

```
{
    abc =     (
                {
            name = abc;
            value = 100;
        }
    );
    pqr =     (
                {
            name = pqr;
            value = 100;
        },
                {
            name = pqr;
            value = 100;
        }
    );
}
```